# object reference error in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

```
var query1 = from a in inputDataRecords
             from b in employeeDataRecords
                  .Where(badgeNumber => a.Responsi == badgeNumber.Badge)
                  .Where(badgeNumber => a.Auth == badgeNumber.Badge)
                  .Where(badgeNumber => a.ByN == badgeNumber.Badge)
                  .DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new {a,
                              responsibleName = b.EmployeeName,
                              authName = b.EmployeeName,
                              createName = b.EmployeeName};
```

gives me an error of: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I know it's because I'm not referencing **b**.

But changing the select to:

```
select new {a, b,
            responsibleName = b.EmployeeName,
            authName = b.EmployeeName,
            createName = b.EmployeeName};
```

doesn't help. QuickWatch on **query1** shows that **b** is null.

Comment: How's b associated to a?

Comment: `.DefaultIfEmpty()` will cause `b` to be null if it doesn't meet your where criteria.

Comment: @Allan - both a and b have a common field of badgeNumber

Answer (score 2):

`b` is null beacuse you specifically called out in your query that `b` should be `null` if the sequence is empty through your use of `DefaultIfEmpty`.  If you don't want to have a `null` `b` item when that sequence is empty, omit that operation.  If you do, then you need to support having a null `b` value in your query.

Answer (score 0):

note that you're using a number of items from `.Where` clauses, which could be null in the collection and thus throw this exception from any one of those lambdas. Try using a `.Where(o => o != null)` on both of those collections, and that may clear up the error.